# How to connect securely using RDP when connecting w/IP

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, certificate

I have a `Windows 8.1` machine that I am trying to connect to a remote server via `RDP` using IP address.

Issue lies with connection type - I'm using IP address and certificate name is DNS name.  So the names don't match:

[image]

> How to connect securely in this situation?  Pushing through will ignore the certificate and open me up to a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://serverfault.com/questions/363707/are-self-signed-ssl-certificates-secure).

**Update**

I have the server certificate installed locally under:

```
Certificates>Trusted Root Certification Authorities
```

So why does RDP still check the name?  **Shouldn't it just check the server cert against trusted certs?**

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot make it work, the certificates work by validating the fqdn so the only way to avoid that error is to start the session using the equivalent to computername.company.local for the target machine

Comment: I want to give benefit of doubt, but can you provide any links that support that?  I am trying to find anything on that, but difficult to search.

Answer (score -1):

In the Local Computer Policy > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Connection Client , there's an option to specify SHA1 thumbprints of certificate that You would like to be consider trusted.

Comment: something something, link-only answers, something something blah blah [help center](http://superuser.com/help).  *I am being sarcastic by the way, with the whole "something something" and "blah blah" since I feel like a broke record at times repeating the same exact phrases about link-only answers.*